# ui-sref no funciona en navbar de bootstrap

Tags: html5, angularjs, bootstrap, ui.router

Estoy usando AngularJS v1.6.9, Bootstrap versión 3.3.0 y ui-router versión v1.0.15 al agregar el `ui-sref` en el navbar de bootstrap, no cambia el estado, simplemente no pasa nada cuando le doy click a algunas opciones del menú.

```
    <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse sub-navbar navbar-fixed-top">
        <div class="container" ng-controller="menuCtrl">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#subenlaces">
                    <span class="sr-only">Interruptor de Navegación</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="#/home">Prueba de concepto</a>
            </div>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="subenlaces">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                     <li><a ui-sref="formbasic">Opción enlace</a></li>
                     <li class="dropdown">
                         <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false">
                             Pasos de formulario
                             <span class="caret"></span>
                         </a>
                         <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                             <li><a ui-sref="paso1">Formulario básico</a></li>
                             <li><a ui-sref="formextensive">Formulario extenso</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
```

en la opciones de Formulario básico y Formulario extenso tampoco funciona si le pongo `href="#/paso1"` o `href="#!/formexensive"`. En el js tengo los estados ya definidos.

```
   // para cualquier ruta que no exista redirecciona a /home
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/home');

    //Estados Posibles para la aplicacion
    $stateProvider
        .state('home', {
            url: '/home',
            views: {
                'pageContent': {
                    templateUrl: 'vistas/home.html',
                    controller:  ''
                }
            }
        })
        .state('paso1', {
            url: '/paso1',
            views: {
                'pageContent': {
                    templateUrl: 'vistas/pasos/paso1.html',
                    controller:  ''
                }
            }
        })
        .state('formextensive', {
            url: '/form-extensive',
            views: {
                'pageContent': {
                    templateUrl: 'vistas/form-extensive.html',
                    controller: ''
                }
            }
        })
```

Si entro directamente a la ruta `http://localhost/pconcepto/#!/paso1` si me manda a la vista.

Answer (score 1):

Recuerda que home.html es donde tienes o debes de tener tu ui-view y a su vez la directiva donde tienes el menu, entonces debes cargarprimero esa vista y despues cargar las otras vistas dentro de tu home.html.

Un buen ejemplo es SB-ADMIN recomednado https://startbootstrap.com/template-overviews/sb-admin-2/

```
.state('dashboard', {
        url: '/dashboard',
        templateUrl: 'vistas/home.html',
        controller:  ''
}).state('dashboard.paso1', {
        url: '/paso1',
        views: {
            'pageContent': {
                templateUrl: 'vistas/pasos/paso1.html',
                controller:  ''
            }
        }
    })
```

Comment: No entiendo bien tu respuesta pero lo que hice fue tener dos `ui-view` en `home.html` una para cargar sólo el menú(navbar) y otro el contenido de  `pagina1` sólo que ahora en cada estado tengo que agregar el menú.